# netstat cannot find Mongo port 27017 even when it is started

Tags: node.js, mongodb

OS: CentOS 6
Mongod Server: 4.4
Node 10.x

I have installed latest Mongo server 4.4 using RPM, start the service using `service mongod start` and using `ps | grep mongo` to know that Mongo is running.

However, when I am running `netstat -aunlp`, I did not see any 27017 port running Mongo??

Here is my `mongod.conf`:

```
#mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017

  # Using either line didn't work, comment out both lines didn't work.
  #bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.
  #bindIp: 0.0.0.0  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.
```

Here is the NodeJS code that use Mongo.  Neither success nor error on console.log shown.

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Connect to database - both lines didn't work
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/somedb');
//mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/somedb', function(err){console.log({"err": err}); });

mongoose.connection.once('connected', function() {
  console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB.')
}).on('error', function(e){
  console.log({"ERR": e});
});
```

Can you all please help me on this?

Thank you very much for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-u restricts to UDP sockets. MongoDB uses a TCP socket.